# Why doesn't this list comprehension work?

Tags: python, list

The purpose of the code is to collect all the chars in wordlist, I did the following:

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
[c for c in word for word in wordlist]
```

The output is strange:

```
['r',
 'r',
 'r',
 'a',
 'a',
 'a',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'i',
 'i',
 'i',
 't',
 't',
 't']
```

I know that I can do it using:

```
[ch for ch in "".join(wordlist)]
```

or

```
[word[i] for word in wordlist for i in range(len(word))]
```

**However my first proposal seems also right, can anyone tell me why the first doesn't work?**

Comment: you need `[c for word in wordlist for c in word]`. It has to do with the order in which the loops are formed and whether or not they are nested.

Comment: [c for word in wordlist for c in word]

Comment: I find this more readable: `list("".join(wordlist))`

Comment: Your code only works if `word = 'rabbit'` was set before running it. Otherwise, the code in your question raises a `NameError` exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `for` statements in the wrong order:

```
[c for c in word for word in wordlist]
```

Should be

```
[c for word in wordlist for c in word]
```

The way to remember the order of the `for` statements in a list comprehension is to imagine how you would write it as a loop.  The order follows the indentation:

```
result = []
for word in wordlist:
    for c in word:
        result.append(c)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the *order* of the `for` statements in the comprehension, they have to be swapped:

```
In [10]: [c for word in wordlist for c in word]
Out[10]: ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

---

Note that the reason it worked for you and did not fail with "`word` is not defined" error, is that you had `word` variable defined as `rabbit` in the scope:

```
In [3]: [c for c in word for word in wordlist]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-decfecd23a92> in <module>()
----> 1 [c for c in word for word in wordlist]

NameError: name 'word' is not defined
In [4]: word = 'rabbit'

In [5]: [c for c in word for word in wordlist]
Out[5]: 
['r',
 'r',
 'r',
 'a',
 'a',
 'a',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'b',
 'i',
 'i',
 'i',
 't',
 't',
 't']
```

Comment: but why the output looks like that?

Comment: I understand, the w in the first is a defined gloabal variable, while w in the second loop is a local variable.